# Copy Problems From Samba to Client

Tags: permissions, samba

Hellow guys, Well my problem is this : One of the thigns that have to do i my work is reintallation of windows for x reasongs. So what we do is back up files and folder to a Samba Server , Format the drive install windows programms etc and copy back the back up from Samba. And there is the problem: Can not copu back the files and folders from Samba to the fresh installtion of windows due Access Denied problem. I am using total commander and never had this kind of problem twice in a row. 2 diffrent systems same job ( back up format) same problem.When i go to the security tab i see user " Everyone" among other with no rights at all. So i have to give total contol to user "Everyone" and there i can copy back files and folders with no Access Denied message. This is a temporarly solution if the back up is too big ( in gb) is loosing time.

Well dont know why is happening that . Is something to do with Samba ? Owner rights? Please help.

Thank you for your time,
Kostas.

Comment: is total commander running as admin, and do the specific files on which you are getting errors already exist?

Comment: Total commander always running as admin the folder files that i want to copy back are not existing ( fresh install)